# Reading From Text File In c++

Tags: c++, string, fstream, ifstream

I am writing a program that takes a single input line consisting of a pattern and the name of a text file.  The program will then search the given text file for the given pattern.

I take the input and convert it into two strings: pattern and file_name
I get an error on the following line:

```
ifstream text(file_name);
```

When I change it to the following, it compiles fine.

```
ifstream text("file_name");
```

Obviously, this is not what I want though since the file name must be determined by the user's input.

How can I make this compile given a changing file name?

Comment: what's type of `file_name` and what's version of compiler?

Comment: Make `file_name` an std::string and it should work fine. (This assumes C++11, because we're in 2013 for crying out loud :v)

Comment: I bet file_name is std::string and you're problem will disappear by using file_name.c_str()

Answer (score 4):

For C++03, [ifstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream) takes `const char*` parameter, you could try:

```
ifstream text(file_name.c_str());
```

While with C++11, your first statement should work.

Comment: Nice. I didn't notice the added overload in c++11. Always finding new surprises.

Comment: That's why we love C++11 :)